# Как осуществить смену text в Label без кнопки

Tags: python, tkinter

Есть два Enter объекта
1-й хранит число
2-й хранит процент (допустим 10)
3-й это Label который пользователь не может изменять , ну поэтому Label
После чего при вводе в 1-й или 2-й Enter объект text Label должен изменится на произведение текста внутри тех двух Enter объектов, без нажатия кнопок (то есть после ввода любого числа в строку Enter)
Как это осуществить без использования кнопок?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Как вы узнаете, что человек ввел число, может он еще добавит какие-то цифры через пару мгновений? Это когда он, допустим, вводит пароль и вы точно знаете сколько цифр он должен ввести, тогда возможна автоматическая обработка.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21837168/python-tkinter-update-when-entry-is-changed